# Session getting null reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

i'm working on a project where i am using sessions for storing message alerts. when new item is added in a database i store success message in Session["message"] and which is used to show a simple message to user. all this is working file every time new message is stored in this session. but when i moved to another page i want to destroy session and after that i want to show new page.
Function for creating sessions:-

```
public void Send_Response(string message, string status)
    {
        Session["message"] = message;
        Session["status"] = status;
    }
```

i can access this session in whole code but when i going to destroy this session it throws null reference exception.
here is the code to setting sessions to null:-

```
 public void Set_Null_Session()
    {
        try
        {
            Response.Cookies["message"].Value = string.Empty;    //not working
            //Session.Abandon();    //not working
            //Session.Remove("message");    //not working
            //Session.Remove("status");    //not working
            Session["message"] = " ";    //not working
            Session["status"] = " ";    //not working
            Session["message"] = null;    //not working
            Session["status"] = null;    //not working
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var error = ex.ToString();
        }

    }
```

i used Session.Remove("message") , session.Abandon() but nothing is working.

i called  Set_Null_Session method in my controller before moving to another page as i want to destroy previous session.

Comment: If Session["message"] = " "; causes a null exception, this might mean you are executing this piece of code not on the webserver with a client request. How do you call this method?

Comment: yes i call Set_Null_Session myself not by a webserver client request.

Comment: How can i set these sessions to null?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like Set_Null_Session does not have access to the Session object. Where is that method defined? And where is it called from? You might need to pass the Session or Request object into the method.

Comment: i am setting vales to sesion and removing them in same controller. As i know sessions are available in whole code

Comment: If `Set_Null_Session` throws an exception, it compiles, and if it compiles, it certainly has access to something called Session, which appears to be of the correct type.